# Domain name stuck on nginx welcome page, when pointing namesilo domain name to AWS ec2 Instance without using route 53

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I am trying to point my own domain name bought from Namesilo to AWS EC2 instance but having a problem that I can visit my Django web app by going to EC2 pubic IP, but if I go to my domain name, it stops in Nginx welcome page.

I do not understand what is going on.

my Nginx configuration file is:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name *.golyy.org 54.79.97.109;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/my_first_django_project/myproject;
    }
    location / {
         include proxy_params;
         proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/my_first_django_project/myproject/app.sock;
    }
}
```

The creation of A record in Namesilo:
[image]

The result when I go to my domain name and EC2 public IP:
[image]

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: add your hostname to `server_name` in your nginx config. You now only have `Public_IP` which means it won't listen to incoming requests for your hostname (it's handled by the default.conf apparently since you see the default nginx page).

Comment: No, I tried before I posted this, it doesnt work.

Comment: Did you restart nginx after changing the config?

Comment: Yes, I did. Just in case that I did not enter the domain in the right way, I updated the Nginx configuration file.

Comment: Since your nginx server is serving a default welcome page, it means another config file is also imported in nginx.conf, beside your config file. Check nginx.conf and the order of the imports. Check also default.conf, that’s usually the file imported by default.

Comment: @dirkgroten Thank you! It is the order of imports that caused the problem. I forgot to delete the default.conf after I configured the Nginx file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For people who may have encountered the same problem, I solved the problem by deleting the default.conf file and I found that after I deleted this it is not necessary to add the domain name, it also works for the domain name as long as they are connected.

Comment: I am using amazon lightsail load balancer and get stuck on nginx welcome page, even when each site behind the load balancer is working properly individually. This solves my problem. Thx.